# Different right-click menus with Flat Remix-GTK themes

Tags: gnome, themes, dock

I have installed Flat-Remix-GTK themes, but the right-click menus are different on desktop and on the Dock. How can i fix them? I prefer on desktop.

Right-click on desktop:

[image: Right-Click On Desktop]

[Right-Click On Dock:

[image: Right-Click on Dock]

Comment: Hi, I think they are themed with shell-themes, do you have `gnome-tweaks` installed or `user-themes` extension installed? then can you provide the shell theme name please?

Comment: Yes they both installed. I took screenshots from gnome-tweaks. Here they are


[1]: https://imgur.com/IVV69n3
[2]: https://imgur.com/FBOeRXX

Comment: Ok, Flat-Remix-Blue-Dark is the shell theme you are using. So you can customize it from there. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Hi, I have installed Flat-Remix-Blue-Dark shell theme on Ubuntu 23.10. The theme is same for both background menu and right-click options on dock. It could be due to some extension you are using. You can turn off all the extensions then re-login and see.

Comment: I realized that it's just not about  flat remix , all of the shell-themes behave like that (without Yaru). 
In addition i closed all extensions, unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: when you turned off all extensions, did you logout and login, then seen the difference?